# Continue this number sequence

Tags: number-sequence

How does this sequence of integers continue?

`4 5 8 8 9 9 12 13`

Not too difficult I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

> 13.

Explanation:

> `ONE` = three letters, +1 = 4
>  `TWO` = three letters, +2 = 5
>  `THREE` = five letters, +3 = 8

etc.

> `NINE` = four letters, +9 = 13

Note

> This sequence has a name (here starting at $0$): https://oeis.org/A095945